Docker: Communication between two .NET APIs
I'm trying to communicate between two .BET APIs inside the docker container. I'm uploading both APIs plus the database through docker-compose, I can access both APIs individually but when I try to send data from one to the other through the route from "API A" to "API B" I get the error below.
2024-11-10 09:19:45 info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
2024-11-10 09:19:45       No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
2024-11-10 09:19:45 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2024-11-10 09:19:45       Now listening on: http://[::]:4000
2024-11-10 09:19:45 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2024-11-10 09:19:45       Now listening on: https://[::]:4001
2024-11-10 09:19:45 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-11-10 09:19:45       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-11-10 09:19:45 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-11-10 09:19:45       Hosting environment: Development
2024-11-10 09:19:45 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-11-10 09:19:45       Content root path: /app
2024-11-10 09:20:06 info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IItemRepository.LogicalHandler[100]
2024-11-10 09:20:06       Start processing HTTP request POST https://itemservice_api/api/Item
2024-11-10 09:20:06 info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IItemRepository.ClientHandler[100]
2024-11-10 09:20:06       Sending HTTP request POST https://itemservice_api/api/Item
2024-11-10 09:20:06 fail: Restaurante_Api.Middlewares.ErrorHandlingMiddleware[0]
2024-11-10 09:20:06       Internal Server Error ErrorMessage { Code = 01.00, Message = Erro interno do servidor. }
2024-11-10 09:20:06       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (itemservice_api:443)
2024-11-10 09:20:06        ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Restaurante_Repositories.Repositories.ItemRepository.Create(CreateItemRequest item) in /src/Restaurante_Repositories/Repositories/ItemRepository.cs:line 25
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Restaurante_UseCases.UseCases.CreateItemUseCase.Execute(CreateItemRequest request) in /src/Restaurante_UseCases/UseCases/CreateItemUseCase.cs:line 20
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Restaurante_Api.Controllers.ItemController.Create(CreateItemRequest request) in /src/Restaurante_Api/Controllers/ItemController.cs:line 21
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Restaurante_Api.Middlewares.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger`1 logger) in /src/Restaurante_Api/Middlewares/ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 16

I built docker-compose as follows
services:
  restaurante_api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=4000
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=4001
    container_name: restaurante_api
    hostname: restaurante_api
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}restauranteapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Restaurante_Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "4001:4001"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      restaurante-bridge:
    depends_on:
      itemservice_api:
        condition: service_started
      sqlserver:
        condition: service_healthy

  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-preview-ubuntu-22.04
    container_name: sqlserver   
    hostname: sqlserver
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=leoQueres123
      - ACCEPT_EULA= Y       
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/sqlserverrestaurante/data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ${APPDATA}/sqlserverrestaurante/log:/var/opt/mssql/log   
    networks:
      - restaurante-bridge
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "leoQueres123" -Q "SELECT 1" -b -o /dev/null
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s 
  
  itemservice_api: 
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=5000
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=5001
    container_name: itemservice_api
    hostname: itemservice_api
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}itemserviceapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ItemService_Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      restaurante-bridge:
    depends_on:
      sqlserver:
        condition: service_healthy


networks:
  restaurante-bridge:    
    driver: bridge
    external: true

networks:
restaurante-bridge:
driver: bridge`
Dockerfile of each application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

# Esta fase é usada para compilar o projeto de serviço
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ItemService_Api/ItemService_Api.csproj", "ItemService_Api/"]
COPY ["ItemService_Borders/ItemService_Borders.csproj", "ItemService_Borders/"]
COPY ["ItemService_Repositories/ItemService_Repositories.csproj", "ItemService_Repositories/"]
COPY ["ItemService_UseCases/ItemService_UseCases.csproj", "ItemService_UseCases/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./ItemService_Api/ItemService_Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ItemService_Api"
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef 
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
RUN dotnet build "./ItemService_Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# Esta fase é usada para publicar o projeto de serviço a ser copiado para a fase final
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ItemService_Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Esta fase é usada na produção ou quando executada no VS no modo normal (padrão quando não está usando a configuração de Depuração)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT dotnet ef database update --environment Development --project src/ItemService_Repositories
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ItemService_Api.dll"]

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4000
EXPOSE 4001

# Esta fase é usada para compilar o projeto de serviço
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Restaurante_Api/Restaurante_Api.csproj", "Restaurante_Api/"]
COPY ["Restaurante_Borders/Restaurante_Borders.csproj", "Restaurante_Borders/"]
COPY ["Restaurante_Repositories/Restaurante_Repositories.csproj", "Restaurante_Repositories/"]
COPY ["Restaurante_UseCases/Restaurante_UseCases.csproj", "Restaurante_UseCases/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Restaurante_Api/Restaurante_Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Restaurante_Api"
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef 
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
RUN dotnet build "./Restaurante_Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# Esta fase é usada para publicar o projeto de serviço a ser copiado para a fase final
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Restaurante_Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Esta fase é usada na produção ou quando executada no VS no modo normal (padrão quando não está usando a configuração de Depuração)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT dotnet ef database update --environment Development --project src/Restaurante_Repositories
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Restaurante_Api.dll"]

Can someone help me understand this problem? I've done everything I could and I can't solve it.

The log reports that it fails when trying to access https://itemservice_api/api/Item. The default port for https:// requests is 443 but your API is not listening on that port, have you tried including the correct port in the URI?

Yes, I tried to set the secondary API port to 5001, 433, localhost, I tried everything, and nothing worked.
I published my study project on github
https://github.com/LeonardoQueres/Docker_.NET_RabbitMq_SQLSERVER.
If anyone wants to download and test it, since it works to register the information in the database, the only problem is the communication with the secondary API through Docker.
Running outside of Docker, the communication works perfectly through localhost.

Hi @LeonardoQueres, Thanks for your sharing, AlwaysLearning's comment is useful. After checking the repo, I found something and share with your below. Waiting for your good news.

After checking stacktrace below, then I tried to check the source code, and I noticed that you hardcoded the BaseUrl.
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Restaurante_Repositories.Repositories.ItemRepository.Create(CreateItemRequest item) in /src/Restaurante_Repositories/Repositories/ItemRepository.cs:line 25
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Restaurante_UseCases.UseCases.CreateItemUseCase.Execute(CreateItemRequest request) in /src/Restaurante_UseCases/UseCases/CreateItemUseCase.cs:line 20
2024-11-10 09:20:06          at Restaurante_Api.Controllers.ItemController.Create(CreateItemRequest request) in /src/Restaurante_Api/Controllers/ItemController.cs:line 21


You should use https://itemservice_api:5001 like below.
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=sqlserver,1433;Database=Restaurantes;User Id=SA;Password=leoQueres123;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  },
  "ItemService": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://itemservice_api:5001/api/Item"
  }
}
//host.docker.internal

